# How does Unreal Engine communicate with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ipc, unreal-engine4

How does Unreal Engine manage to trigger builds within Visual Studio even though its running in a separate process?

I think it's able to create files and reload a project, even open a file at a specific line!

Is it possible to control VS from another application? I can't seem to find any information regarding a socket or any other IPC mechanism that VS allows.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding UE4**

It doesn't communicate with Visual Studio process. Here's what happens in the situations that you've described:

1. Building. If you mean recompiling your project on the fly. This is what happens:

   ```
   [2016.09.28-08.51.49:868][298]Launching UnrealBuildTool... [D:/_UE4/4.12.5_from_source/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe MyProject -ModuleWithSuffix MyProject 1497 Win64 DebugGame -editorrecompile -canskiplink "C:/MyProject.uproject"  -2015]
   ```

   So UE4 is just calling one of the tools that builds your project and loads new libraries on the fly. Inside UnrealBuildTool you can find references to VS compiler:

   ```
   string CompilerExe = Path.Combine(WindowsPlatform.GetVSComnToolsPath(WindowsCompiler.VisualStudio2015), "../../VC/bin/cl.exe");
   ```

   Loading dlls during runtime is also a doable task.
2. Creating VS projects. This can be done programmatically, there is a [guide on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228767.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)
3. Creating and opening files. Creating files is easy. And you can open one by just calling vs executable with a filename argument. As for the specific line, I'm not sure if that is possible. When I click *Go to definition* inside blueprint it's just opening another instance of Visual Studio with the file opened on top. But I'm not sure, there can be a command line argument that would jump you to the specific line.

**Conclusion**

So I don't think that it's possible to communicate with a running Visual Studio and Unreal doesn't do that. It's just uses tools provided by Visual Studio to do the job. I recommend checking out the source code of the UE4 tools, it's enlightening.